# Can I use old style individual faucets on a bathroom vanity?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, code-compliance

We have an old home and would like to keep with the period where possible. I have a marble vanity top with individual faucets for hot and cold rather than a single spigot for both. I can buy brand new replacement faucets that look exactly correct. Does anyone know if that is allowed by current plumbing code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plumbing code is generally unconcerned with the style of whatever fixture you choose to install, only that the fixture work properly and be installed properly.

Answer (score 1):

Standard bathroom faucets come in versions that have the faucet handles on 4" centers, 8" centers, or separate pieces that can be placed at any distance apart.

I have never heard of a jurisdiction whose building codes require a specific distance for handle centers. But to be certain, check with the local plumber who will be installing the fixture.

Comment: The first part of your answer is true, but doesn't seem relevant to the question.

Comment: The Q & A is meant  to have relevance beyond the original OP. Thought it might help others.

Answer (score 0):

Plumbing code allows this. Styles are not covered under building codes, generally safety and quality are what building codes are after.